# Using HTML OR CSS, How do I test a field for populated or not? I need to print different lines depending on contents of a variable

Tags: html, css, sap-successfactors

I am working on a learning certificate within SAP successfactors, In this tool I can type HTML and CSS. I cant use javascript.

I want to print the word 'Instructor' if the field <INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> isnt populated and print the field contents if it is populated.

I am really struggling because I don't know CSS or HTML. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

This is the line I am having problems with.

```html
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> = NULL">Instructor</span></p>
```

I want it to only populate the word 'Instructor' if the field is not populated, but it is showing the word 'Instructor' every time weather the field is populated or not.

I have tried:

```html
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> IS BLANK">Instructor</span></p> 
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> IS NOT PRESENT ">Instructor</span></p>
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> = """>Instructor</span></p>
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> ==""">Instructor</span></p>
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> IS NULL">Instructor</span></p>
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> = NULL">Instructor</span></p>
<p class="instructor-name" ><span data-show-if="!<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/>">Instructor</span></p>
```

all of these show the word 'Instructor' when there is data in the INSTRUCTOR_NAME field.

FULL CODE:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
}

div#content-wrapper {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-spacing: normal;
  style="display: inline-block";
}

h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

p.completion-date {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 19px;
}

p.instructor-name {
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block
}

p.item-id {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-style: bold;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

p.divider {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-style: bold;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#midinit {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  max-width: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
}

#name {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#midinit,
#name {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <h1>Certificate of Completion</h1>
  <h2>This certifies that</h2>
  <p id="name">
    <USER_FIRST_NAME/> </p>
  <p id="midinit">
    <USER_MIDDLE_INITIAL/> </p>
  <p id="name">
    <USER_LAST_NAME/>
  </p>
  <h4>Has successfully completed</h4>
  <h5>
    <CPNT_TITLE/>
  </h5>
  <p class="item-id">
    <CPNT_ID/>
  </p>
  <p class="completion-date">Completed on
    <COMPLETION_DATE/>
  </p>
  <p class="divider">___________________________________________________</p>
  <p class="instructor-name">
    <INSTRUCTOR_NAME/>
  </p>
  <p class="instructor-name"><span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> = NULL">Instructor</span></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in HTML and CSS without using JavaScript, you can use the CSS pseudo-class :empty to detect if the <INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> field is empty. You can then use the :before pseudo-element to add the text "Instructor" before the

tag that contains the <INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> field.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
}
div#content-wrapper {
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: normal;
    style="display: inline-block" ;
}
h4 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
p.completion-date {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
}
p.instructor-name {
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block
}
p.item-id {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-style: bold;
    margin-top: 0px;
 }
p.divider {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-style: bold;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#midinit{
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 18px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block ;
}
#name{
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#midinit,#name
{display: inline-block ;
}

/* add this CSS */
p.instructor-name:before {
    content: "Instructor123";
}
p.instructor-name

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <h1>Certificate of Completion</h1>
    <h2>This certifies that</h2>
    <p id="name"><USER_FIRST_NAME/></p>
    <p id="midinit"><USER_MIDDLE_INITIAL/></p>
    <p id="name"><USER_LAST_NAME/></p>
    <h4>Has successfully completed</h4>
    <h5><CPNT_TITLE/></h5>
    <p class="item-id"><CPNT_ID/></p>
    <p class="completion-date">Completed on <COMPLETION_DATE/></p>
    <p class="divider">___________________________________________________</p>
    <p class="instructor-name">
      <span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> != ''"><INSTRUCTOR_NAME/></span>
    </p>
    <p class="instructor-name">
      <span data-show-if="<INSTRUCTOR_NAME/> = ''">Instructor</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn, for your answer. Unfortunately it still prints both the contents of the field and the word 'Instructor'. Can you think of any other way to solve this problem?